# Having trouble writing lines into a document

Tags: python

I need this script to show on which lines every word occurs. The problem is that i can't get the lines to be written in the document

```py
def WordOnLine():
    file = open("tekstbestand.txt","r")
    file2 = open("aantalwoorden","a")
    lineN = 0
    for line in file:
        sent = line.split()
        lineN += 1
        for word in sent:
            if len(word) >= 4:
                if word in file2:
                    word = word.replace(word,word+" " +lineN + "\n")
                else:
                    file2.append(word + " " + str(lineN) + "\n")
    file.close()
    file2.close()
WordOnLine()
```

Comment: use file2.write not file2.append

Comment: didn't change anything, it's giving me the following error: "io.UnsupportedOperation: not readable" Not sure what this means

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few stylistic changes and some corrections to get you a little bit further, a couple of which have already been pointed out. If you are running Python 3, you can remove statement 1 (**from __future__** etc.). On line 4, you need to open aantalwoorden specifying "a+" so that the file can be read as well as appended. This will eliminate the io.UnsupportedOperation exception. Line 4 also opens the two files using a "with" statement to wrap the block it encloses in a "context manager" that will automatically close the two files on termination of that block. Statement 12 has been modified so that if it is ever executed you will not get an exception trying to concatenate a string with an integer. Finally, statement 12 is a simpler way to write your output to file2 using the Python 3 print function.

As for your program logic, I make no claims that it does what you intend.

```
from __future__ import print_function #1

def WordOnLine():
    with open("tekstbestand.txt","r") as file, open("aantalwoorden","a+") as file2: #4
        lineN = 0
        for line in file:
            sent = line.split()
            lineN += 1
            for word in sent:
                if len(word) >= 4:
                    if word in file2:
                        word = word.replace(word,word+" " +str(lineN) + "\n") #12
                    else:
                        print(word, lineN, file=file2)
WrdOnLine()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
file2 = open("aantalwoorden","a+")
```

And

```
file2.write(word + " " + str(lineN) + "\n")
```

Here is some explanation:
https://www.guru99.com/reading-and-writing-files-in-python.html